# Why is my iOS app getting killed automatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I am facing very strange problem in my app. My app is getting killed when I keep my app in background for long time. I have checked the memory usage of the app in the 'instruments' tool, the live memory usage of the app was 1.48mb and overall usage was 6.18mb, which is not very high. Still my is getting killed.

I have checked my app even if there are few apps running in background say around 4 still it's killing my app. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Post your code for reference.

Comment: @user1673099 What code should be posted? The whole app?

Comment: Have you read *anything* about backgrounding on iOS?  Your app only has a limited amount of time to run in the background.

Comment: Did you declare background processing/background services in your app? Otherwise, the app may be killed any time. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20 for guidance on how to enable background processing.

Comment: @nneonneo Actually I have used beginBackgroundExecution for performing one task when app goes to background but I have stopped this process one my task get complete.

Comment: What do you mean by "killed" ? The app stop running code in background or the app is not appearing in the background app list after a double tap on home button ?

Comment: If your app is not a voip app or music playing app it the background execution time is limited to 10 minutes

Comment: Thank you guys for you reply. But I am not using any background processing. Also My app is there in background running apps, but it is getting back to home screen though I am on inner screen exactly like when app crashes.